# Custom annotation for method in controller that extends an abstract controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-boot-starter

What I have to do is pretty simple using interceptors but I was really hoping for a more elegant solution based on annotations. The thing is that my "solution" doesn't really work and I do not know why. Maybe this isn't even possible.

My basic stack is:
spring boot 1.4.1:

- spring-boot-starter-web
- spring-boot-starter-aop
- spring-boot-starter-jdbc
- spring-boot-starter-cache

spring-beans 4.3.4
and various other utilities and test jars.

I have several controllers that extend an abstract controller. This abstract controller must prepare a connection and then each controller is using its own specific implementation placed in **acquire()** method. From time to time some cron jobs are hitting this endpoints. We want to make an audit on some controllers/jobs but not necessarily all of them. 
So I was thinking about adding a custom annotation where the audit should be.

```
public abstract class ImportController { 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/checkout", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public String importEntities() {
         //some code here ....
         MyResult result = acquire(param);
         //some code again ....
    }

     public abstract MyResult acquire(MyParam param)
}
```

Implementation that needs audit:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/cars")
public class CarsImportController extends ImportController {

     @Override
     @MyJobAudit // <--- this should add a pointcut used for Audit logging
     public MyResult acquire(MyParam param) {
          //cars specific code
     }
}
```

Implementation that doesn't need audit

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/tomatoes")
public class TomatoesImportController extends ImportController {

     @Override
     //no audit annotation
     public MyResult acquire(MyParam param) {
           //tomatoes specific code
     }
}
```

My JobAudit annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface MyJobAudit {
}
```

and the aspects class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SystemAspectArchitecture {
    @Pointcut("@annotation(MyJobAudit)")
    public void auditableJob() {
    }
}
```

I tried to put my annotation on various service classes and it works. But not on **acquire()** method. Something is definitely wrong here. I can't figure out what...

Comment: Can you confirm that your `acquire()` method is really `public`? Because Spring Aspects only work on public methods.

Comment: Yes, it's public

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on the invocation of your advised code. You see, you have the following code defined:

```
@GetMappein(value = "/checkout")
public String getCheckout() {
   //some code here ....
   MyResult result = acquire(param); //Uh oh!!!
   //some code again ....
}
```

But the problem is that the advised code is defined in a proxy that Spring creates for you (and which in case of controllers you never see), but your invocation of the `acquire(param)` method above is not done in the Spring proxy, but directly on your concrete class, in other words it is equivalent to saying `this.acquire(param)`, but the code is advised in the proxy of `this`, and not just on `this` (your concrete object).

The way to solve the problem is get access to your current proxy. I solved it as follows.

First, enable `expose-proxy` in your application.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(exposeProxy = true)
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication, args);
    }
}
```

Then, in the concrete class, where you intend to make an invocation of a method that is supposed to be advised, you do the following:

```
@RestController
public class ConcreteController {

    @GetMapping("/checkout")
    public String getSomething() {
        Object proxy = AopContext.currentProxy();
        return ((ConcreteController) proxy).acquire("Luke Skywalker");
    }

    @Auditable
    public String acquire(Object param) {
        return "Hello World, " + param;
    }

}
```

The `AopContext.currentProxy()` will give you access to the proxy of `this` controller where the advice for `acquire(params)` is actually defined. And that'll work as expected.

I understand that the only workaround for this would be to use true AOP and not just Spring proxies. And if you use true AOP then you will have to do some form of code weaving that will advice the code either during compiling or loading time. That way the code would be advised directly on the concrete class and not just on the dumb Spring proxies. Using true AOP `this.acquire()` would be advised via instrumentation at compile time or load time. But if you only use Spring proxies, then you cannot straightforwardly do things like direct method invocations within an advised class, you need to make sure to go through the proxy every time you do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Edwin! Definitely must learn more about the inner and hidden tricks that Spring does and "proxies" is one of them.